# Can (으)ㄹ바에는 and 기보다 be completely interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

i have 2 sentence as follows:

> 맛없는 밥을 **먹을 바에는** 차라리 굶는 것이 더 낫습니다.(Better to starve than to eat tasteless rice)
>
> 그 사람이랑 여행을 **갈 바에는** 차라리 그냥 집에 있겠어요 (If I have to go on a trip with him, I would rather just stay at home.)

Can these sentences be rewritten as

> 맛없는 밥을 **먹기보다** 차라리 긂는 것이 더 낫습니다
>
> 그 사람이랑 여행을 **가기보다** 차라리 그냥 집에 있겠어요.

Can I replace (으)ㄹ 바에는 with 기보다 like above? And Can (으)ㄹ 바에는 and 기보다 be completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your two cases mean essentially the same thing and *would* be comprehensible to a native speaker, the two phrases in question carry subtly different meanings.

"~할 바에는" conveys more of a "would rather", whereas "~보다" itself carries only a better preference for something else.

It follows also that you may omit the "차라리" after "~할 바에는" because the phrase already contains that shade of meaning. E.g., "맛 없는것 먹을 바에는 굶는게 나아."

Finally note that these meaning differences manifest from the colloquial sense in how the phrase is used extremely commonly, and not necessarily when you break down the definitions of "하다" and "바."